# Updating SQL view, enforcing constraints on foreign table values

Tags: sql, view, constraints

I have a view that joins two tables together.

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers
ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID;
```

If I update CustomerName, it updates it in the Customers table.
How do I configure this view so when I update a customer name, it will only accept names that exist in cust table, or fail otherwise

UPDATE: MS SQL

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot actually update a view directly, this just gives you a "view" of the data in that exists in tables. There are a couple of options, you can create integrity constraints against the customer table, handle it through the application front end or if you do want to issue update statements against the view directly most rdbms offer an instead of trigger on the views which allows you to specify how the underlying tables should be updated if a statement is executed against the view.

Comment: You can in fact `Update` directly through a View in SQL Server, as long as it is a writebale View and you are only updating writeable columns from a single table at a time.  You do not need an Indexed View or a View Trigger to do this.

Comment: What I mean is that the view itself is just an abstraction of the data in the tables. What you are actually updating is the underlying tables. I accept that the method for issuing an update command against a view will be different among different rdbms and I was not aware that a trigger would not be required for this in SQL-Server. I believe it is in Oracle and SQLite.

Comment: After further investigation it seems that the trigger on the view is only required in some circumstances to avoid ambiguity etc. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175158%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Comment: AFAIK, this feature called "Updateable Views" is supported by most of the major DBMS's (Oracle, IBM DB2, Microsoft SQL Server, ..).

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said what DBMS you are using yet, but for SQL Server, add `WITH CHECK OPTION` to your View definition.  If the `UPDATE` is actually going through the View (normal for ADO.Net and most other access methods) then this will check it.

If, however, it is decomposing to the underlying tables and then updating *them*, this will not work (some tools and older access methods do try to do this).  You can stop this with appropiate security settings, but that might prevent them from working altogether.